# Correct way to set indent to zero in newcommand

Tags: spacing, macros

I define a new command to number the problems in a chapter:

```
\newcounter{problemNo} %problem counter
\setcounter{problemNo}{1} %start at one
\newcommand\problem[1]{\textbf{Problem \thechapter.
\arabic{problemNo} }#1 \par\smallskip\stepcounter{problemNo}\noindent}
```

This code has some indentation problems:

[image: f]

I also tried to use `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`, but with no luck:

```
\newcommand\problem[1]{\textbf{Problem \thechapter.\arabic{problemNo}
}#1 \par\smallskip\stepcounter{problemNo}\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}}
```

[image: ff]

In fact, now the indent is zero everywhere.

What is the right way for removing the indentation only after the `\problem` command?

---

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\newcounter{problemNo}
\setcounter{problemNo}{1}
\newcommand\problem[1]{\textbf{Problem \thechapter.
\arabic{problemNo} }#1 \par\smallskip\stepcounter{problemNo}\noindent}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Problems}

\problem{Solve this problem:}
Problem statement.\\

\problem{Solve this problem too:}
Problem statement.\\


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't use `\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]`? Load `amsthm`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{problemNo}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theproblemNo}{\thechapter.\arabic{problemNo}}
\newcommand{\problem}[1]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\bigskipamount}
  \refstepcounter{problemNo}%
  \noindent\textbf{Problem \theproblemNo}
  #1
  \par\nobreak
  \smallskip
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Problems}

\problem{Solve this problem:}
Problem statement.

\problem{Solve this problem too:}
Problem statement.

\end{document}
```

What changed:

- Proper definition of `problemNo` counter to reset with every `[chapter]` and have a representation that includes the chapter number representation (`\thechapter`).
- A `\problem` starts by adding some space up to `\bigskipamount`.
- The `problemNo` counter is stepped just before setting **Problem X.Y**; this allows for proper referencing if you use `\label`-`\ref`.
- After setting the problem statement, a `\par`agraph break is initiated *without* a possibility for a page break (thanks to `\nobreak`). This avoids having **Problem X.Y** at the bottom of the page and the problem statement at the top of the following page.

Subsequent paragraphs of a problem statement will have a regular `\parindent`. If you want to avoid this altogether, add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to your preamble.

---

A completely different approach would be to define your `\problem` as an environment similar to that of a theorem. However, this would require a change in your input.

Answer (score 6):

What about this one?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Problems}

\begin{problem}
Solve this problem:\\ Problem statement.
\end{problem}

Text in middle.

\begin{problem}
Solve this problem:\\ Problem statement.
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Solve this problem:\\ Problem statement.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```